# What are the iron bars and threaded rods sticking up out of my backyard?

Tags: steel, bolts

What are these bolts and metal rods sticking out the ground?

[image]

Comment: Were they literally "sticking up" or did you uncover them while digging?

Comment: They were sticking up and I wanted to remove them so the dogs wouldn't get hurt so I dug a little bit but was afraid maybe there was Electric in there or something

Comment: Some sort of industrial equipment or base for such, probably not related to the home itself.

Comment: Bolts coming up out of the ground could be left over mounting hardware from some kind of platform (radio antenna tower for example). The cluster of threaded rods and the bars is NOT likely from that however. I was also thinking maybe it was a hole that someone dumped a bunch of scrap into, but the vertical nature of the orientations makes that unlikely.

Answer (score 2):

It’s a modified type of “sheet piling” used for earth retention/ engineering.

I’d guess there is (was) some slope at your site that the previous home owner wanted to control. I’d guess that they started a project and then abandoned it because it looks like some preliminary site work.

If you remove it, be careful as it could loosen some surrounding areas that could start moving.

The threaded rods are obviously set for future connections, building, equipment, shoring, retaining, etc.

It will be difficult to cut off, based on its size and shape. (The curved connections between the flanges and web indicate it’s structural steel...probably A36 steel, minimum.)

Comment: So what would be your suggestion on how to cover the sharp ends to prevent injury to humans or dogs?

Comment: @JimStewart Because no one knows WHY the structural metal is installed at that location in that manner, I would not remove it. Rather, I’d cover it up with 1) a landscape berm, or 2) a wood enclosure. Otherwise, the only other option would be to cut the tops off, but that could be time consuming and expensive.

Comment: @JimStewart Oh, one could dig down and investigate. If it’s less than 3-4’ deep, then you could consider removing it.

Comment: would a sawzall with blade for metal cut through it

Comment: @TerrellMontgomery It would be worth a try, wouldn’t it? Torching it off is going to take awhile.

Comment: Some contractor that could wheel in a set of oxygen / accelletlyene tanks with a cutting torch could cut those all off within a short time. Shouldn't be that expensive either....just have to find the person with the gear.

Comment: You might be able to pull them out with a "high-lift" jack, I pulled up some similar stuff with one. You would/could grab onto that nut with the jack, same with the steel bars if you bent them over or punched a hole in them.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it Yes, and hopefully they’re not set in concrete.